# Sanitize 'String' Argument w/ Anorm?

Tags: scala, anorm

Given:

```
def unsafeF(x: String): String = 
   s"select * from TABLE WHERE x = $x"
```

Is it possible to sanitize `unsafeF`'s input, `x`, via a function call to `x` in `$x`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to sanitize it, as long as you use the proper Anorm String interpolation, not the standard one.

```
SQL"select * from TABLE WHERE x = $x"
```

> You can see the Anorm interpolation in the [Anorm documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm#SQL-queries-using-String-Interpolation).

Comment: What if I'm not using `SQL"..."`?

Comment: Either you use `SQL".."` interpol, or `SQL("..")` + `.on(..)`.That's the way to safely pass values as SQL parameters. Please read the documentation.